# Shell script running binaries in multiple terminals

Tags: shell-script

I'm pretty new to shell scripts but I have some binaries I'd like to run in a loop over a set of different input files. I need them to be run in sequence: repeat after current one complete.

I got as far as trying to run two process in separate terminals and saving the pid but when I go to kill the process, it looks like the pids have changed.

```
#!/bin/bash
gnome-terminal -e "vi" & MAIN_PID=$!
gnome-terminal -e "gedit" & SIM_PID=$!
echo "MAIN Process ID is " $MAIN_PID
echo "SIM Process ID is " $SIM_PID
sudo kill $MAIN_PID
```

Terminal Output:

```
MAIN Process ID is  8532
SIM Process ID is  8542
# Option “-e” is deprecated and might be removed in a later version of gnome-terminal.
# Use “-- ” to terminate the options and put the command line to execute after it.
kill: (8532): No such process
user:~/Desktop$ ps -A | grep vi
 1026 ?        00:00:01 dconf-service
 8541 pts/3    00:00:00 vi
user:~/Desktop$ ps -A | grep gedit
 8550 pts/4    00:00:00 gedit
```

If there's an easier way to get what I want started, I'd like to know as well. I was planning to start these processes and check some condition to know when they have completed, kill the process and repeat with different set of inputs.

Answer (score 0):

When you run `gnome-terminal -e "vi" & MAIN_PID=$!`, you are not capturing the PID of `vi` in `MAIN_PID`; you are capturing the PID of that instance of `gnome-terminal`.  If you want to find the PID of a process owned by `gnome_terminal`, you could do some magic on the output of `pstree`:

```
pstree -p $MAIN_PID | grep -o 'vim([0-9]*) | grep -o '[0-9]*'
```

To check whether a process still exists, you can use `kill -0` which will not send any signals, and either return with an exit code of 0 if the process exists, or 1 if it does not.